# DateTime specifier with spaces

Tags: c#, datetime

I have for example following date time

```
 DateTime dt = new DateTime(2013,18,04,22,23,0);
```

this date should be represented like

```
18-04-2013 22:23    Environment.NewLine
```

Worth to mention is there are spaces between number 3 (of 22:23) and `Environment.NewLine`.
So, field length is 20characters from beginning to E letter (of `Environment.NewLine`).

How can I represent date in this format with spaces?

Comment: `dt.ToString(yourFormat).PadRight(desiredTotalLength) + Environment.NewLine;`?

Comment: I think your constructor parameters are wrong. They are `(year, month, day, ...)` and 18 is not a valid month.

Comment: Have a look at here: http://www.csharp-examples.net/align-string-with-spaces/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a combination of standard date formatting and non-date-specific string format codes:

```
string.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm}    \n", dt);
```

or if the length "20" is important:

```
string.Format("{0,-20:MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm}\n", dt);
```

this effectively "pads" the string to 20 characters and left-justifies it.  That way you're still at 20 characters even if someone decides to change the date format (e.g. not pad with zeros)

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP wants the [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) _constant_, not the _static string_.

Comment: "beggining to E letter" might be a bit misleading.

Comment: Yes that was misleading - I took it literally thinking it may be for a code-gen template or something.

Answer (score 2):

```
string.Format("{0,-20}  {1}", DateTime.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"), Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: There can be other more efficient (read: elegant) ways to do this too

Comment: You could use `{0,-20}{1}` (OP mentioned 20 character margin).

Comment: I think you need `"HH"` instead of `"hh"` for 24-hour format.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you fix the `DateTime` assignment so month is before day:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2013, 4, 18, 22, 23, 0);
String.Format("{0,-20}{1}",
    dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"),
    "Environment.NewLine" //*/ Environment.NewLine // Whichever you want
);
```

`Format` allows you to specify space padding in the formatter, so `{0,-20}` means display with a 20-character column, align left. Likewise, `{0,20}` would do 20 characters, right align.